# CSS Control gradient stops

Tags: html, css

I currently have this

```
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

with the css

```
#grad1 {
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, grey, white);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9g2zrqse/

im trying to make it just so there is more white then there is grey

Answer (score 0):

You add stops in modern CSS by using % and the color for that stop (I've also included older versions, e.g. webkit-gradient which used the non-standard "color-stop"):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%, rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(21%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(229,229,229,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 21%,rgba(229,229,229,1) 100%); /* W3C */
```

You will also notice I used `rgba` colors instead of "grey" or "white". Using the preset names for colors is a bad idea. It's vague and could be different in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look **[HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)** (at the *Using Multiple Color Stops* section)

You could add another `grey` to your code